# Javascript for lego Mindstorms

Tags: javascript, node.js, lego-mindstorms

I've been assigned to a project aiming at programming Lego Mindstorms with JavaScript. However, I can't find many good resources regarding the use of JS with Mindstorms. Does anyone have any ?

Also, I don't really get how I can, for example, make the wheels turn using JS. From what I understood I need to use Node.js.

Comment: I have no idea how to do this, but here is a link of a MATLAB implementation. Maybe you could use this as a starting point to see, what is necessary? http://www.mindstorms.rwth-aachen.de/trac/wiki/Download4.08

Comment: This question is, in my opinion, too broad. You should find your own way to move on and come back with a specific problem, such questions, in stackoverflow, are usually considered off topic, as far as i know. In any case, there seems to a large variety of nodejs APIs to control lego mindstorm components, but it's literally up to you to understand what kind of communication you want to use (either bluetooth or wireless or through cables). Nodejs is quite advanced in javascript in any case, you should first understand the basics of javascript syntax and mechanics first.

Comment: Also, for reference, you may take a look at this http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/679/is-there-any-other-way-to-program-the-lego-mindstorms-nxt-other-than-the-provide

Comment: A simple Google search will show you have at least 2 libraries for controlling Lego Mindstroms using Node.JS: EV3 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ev3) and node-mindstorm-bt (https://github.com/davsebamse/node-mindstorm-bt)

Comment: Are you using NXT or EV3? For EV3, there is [ev3dev](http://www.ev3dev.org/) which allows you to use many different programming languages including JavaScript.

Comment: I had a general question on JS options for Mindstorms and Google brought this page as one of top results.  This question has a good answer.  This Q&A are useful to me, and not too broad IMO.  It's a high level question that requires a high level answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can use http://www.ev3dev.org/ as an alternative firmware, you can install and run node.js on the ev3. ev3dev is a debian linux based distribution and offers a wide range of packages.

One catch you will be stuck a node.js-0.10, since newer node.js (0.12) versions use a newer version of v8 (js engine) and that does not support the old arm-9 that runs the ev3 anymore (or more precisely it now requires vfp-3 that only arm-v7 cpus have).

Answer (score 0):

Lego don't allow javascript on LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 Home Edition.
But I don't know about third party softwares.

I hope support for javascript will come soon.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [Robot JavaScript](https://robotjavascript.com).  This is a Windows based compiler downloaded from the Microsoft App Store that allows you to compile JavaScript directly into an EV3 robot for execution.  No need to alter the EV3 operating system.  This uses the Firmware from LEGO.